# How do I get a signed cookie from the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to restrict access to a route that communicates with a gem directly, and I cannot use a method of my `ApplicationController`.

Since I don't use an authentication gem like Devise, I don't have access to `authenticate` helpers in the routes file.

How do I access my **signed cookies**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement a constraint as indicated in the Ruby on Rails guide, and use this to access your cookies:

```
cookies = ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar.build(request, request.cookies)
```

You can now access your signed or encrypted cookies as usual:

```
cookies.signed[:user_id]
```